# I need to work with 64-bit ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, mapping, 64bit

I work with 64-bit Bentley WaterGEMS and it uses 64-bit Microsoft Access Database Engine. Opening XLSX files in ArcMap (via Add XY Data ...) needs 32-bit Microsoft Access Database Engine. Both 32 and 64-bit Microsoft Access Database Engine can not be installed simultaneously.

How can I do with this problem? Does ArcMap have 64-bit version?

Comment: You might be able to convert your xlsx to an ArcGIS Table or CSV before running Add XY Data. This Tool uses pure Python modules to read xlsx files.
[Excel and CSV Conversion Tools]:https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=f3d91b8f852042e289e09a7ec8342431

Answer (score 4):

ArcMap is 32-bit app. However you can install 64-bit background processing, but you will need 32-bit and 64-bit client as well to connect to databases. So I don't think you can achieve your goal with ArcMap.

> For example, if you're using tools with 64-bit background processing
>   and enterprise geodatabase data, you'll need to make sure you have
>   both the 32- and 64-bit client libraries installed on your machine.
>   ArcGIS for Desktop will continue to use the 32-bit libraries, and
>   background will use the 64-bit libraries.

source:
http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/executing-tools/64bit-background.htm

Have you tried using ArcGIS Pro which is 64bit app?